# ring resonator physics resonanse formula logic

Tags: resonance

Hello there is a problem and a solution to it ,which shows how to find the resonance.
There is a solution to the problem which basicly looks at a periodisity of an exponent.
but how they got to this conclusion that periodisity of exponent is linked to resonanse?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hint: think of what might "resonance" mean in this context, what does resonance mean?

Comment: resonanse mean the magnetic energy cancels the capacitatice,pure resistance remains.
there is no oscilation .all the power falls on the resistive part.
How does it link to the periodisty of the exponent?Thanks.

Comment: That is your problem! No, resonance does no mean that. Assume a completely lossless situation without any resistance, now read your book again or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration

Comment: Hello hyportnex,When the two exponential terms are equated, e^(jbetaaphi) = e^(jn*phi), it means that the wave propagating around the ring resonator completes an integer number of wavelengths within the circumference of the ring

How this condition means resonance?

Comment: one more hint (it is a homework problem, you have to solve it yourself): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_wave especially the section "Standing wave on a string with two fixed ends"

Comment: Yes, that is it, integer number of wavelengths around the perimeter! Now that you know when it is "resonating" your question is why we we call it that way. Because at that frequency corresponding to integer number of wavelengths it can do keep oscillating without feeding it once it starts (assuming lossless). If you stretch a pair of identical wires next to each other and you hit one then through the air they effect each other mildly (loose coupling) so that the *other* will also vibrate at the frequencies with integer number of wavelengths: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sympathetic_resonance.

Comment: hello hyportnex,how do we know that our wave goes radially in a ring resonator?
Thanks.

Comment: the wave goes around the perimeter  in the circle not radially because the *width* of the strip is much less than the wavelength. At very high frequency, such that the width is of the same order as the wavelength there can be other resonances and other form of oscillations than the one in this question. Think of a string stretched and vibrating between two fixed points, normally the oscillation is between them but if the string is very thick you can have transversal shear oscillations on it.

Comment: Hello hyportnex,So if we look in general disk and ring. we have a PEC on the top and buttom and PMC on the walls.So E-field will be perpandicular to the plane and H-field wil be parralel to the plane.I have simulted this structure as shown in the pictures bellow and i dont see the wall turning arround the circumfrance.
Could you help me understand what kind of EM mode we are talking about in this situation? Thanks. 

https://ibb.co/kBzcMvV
https://ibb.co/nMQrvcf
https://ibb.co/pLWpRzy

Comment: top/ bottom PEC and sidewalls PMC, the lowest order mode is TEM

Comment: Hello hyportnex,I cant seen  where is the wave that goes around the circumfrance in TEM mode.when you talk about the wave you talk about the pointing vector EXH going around the circomfrance? when i look in the simulation how can i spot the wave going around the circomrance?

Comment: e^{beta*a*phi}  from what field its being taken?

Comment: On your problem page: "so that curvature effect can be neglected". therefore it is just a [planar transmission line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_transmission_line)